# Do I really need hiveserver2?

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I am using hive v.0.13.

I am confuse with the function of hiveserver2.  If my data is in hdfs, I have tried to simply use "hive" CLI to create external table without having hiveserver2 started hence the question is this correct?  or did I miss out anything?  If yes then what, if not then when do I really need hiveserver2?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Hive 0.13, HiveServer2 provides support for sending Thrift RPC messages over HTTP transport (HIVE-4752). This is particularly useful to support a proxying intermediary between the client and the server (for example, for load balancing or security reasons). Currently, you can run HiveServer2 in either TCP mode or the HTTP mode, but not in both. This is where it will be useful.

ref: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2